# Erro "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" Android

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde galera, estou precisando de uma ajuda para entender melhor como resolver esse erro que aparece no terminar:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

Logo apos aparecer o erro dos frames o app é fechado dando erro. Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso antes para me ajudar.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_radio_no_ar, container, false);
        listViewPrograms = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.programacao_list);


        am = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        afChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
                    stopPlaying();
                } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                    stopPlaying();
                }
            }
        };

        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }

        radioList = new Radio(getActivity()).getAll();

        if (radioList.size() > 0) {
            updateRadio();
            mountView();
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

Play na stream:

```
private void startPlaying() {
        if(urlStreaming == null) {
            urlStreaming = objRadio.getStreaming();
        }

        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        threadRadio = Thread.currentThread();
        threadRadio = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    player.setDataSource(urlStreaming);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    notifyErroPlayer();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    notifyErroPlayer();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    notifyErroPlayer();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    notifyErroPlayer();
                }
                try {
                    player.prepare();
                    final int result = focusOnPlay();
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED && player != null) {
                                player.start();
                                updateListPrograms();
                                shape = getDraw(getContext(), R.drawable.stop_button);
                                buttonPlay.setImageDrawable(shape);
                                setStateAudio(true);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    notifyErroPlayer();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    notifyErroPlayer();
                }
            }
        });
        threadRadio.start();
    }
```

**UpdateListPrograms que é onde iniciar e faz com que de o erro da main thread**

```
private void updateListPrograms() {
   final Handler handlerProgramacao = new Handler();
   handlerProgramacao.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          inittask = new InitTask();
          inittask.execute();
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Isso indica que está a executar processamentos demorados na *main thread*. Normalmente isso é resolvido mudando esses processamentos para outra *thread*. Isso só por si não justifica o app fechar com erro. Coloque na pergunta o *logcat* para sabermos que erro é.

Comment: Tenho a Thread Principal, ela inicia verificando se existe uma lista de programação da radio no banco, caso não exista ele busca no json e salva. Apos isso ele inicia isso 

threadRadio = Thread.currentThread();
        threadRadio = new Thread(new Runnable() {

e dentro disso é onde dá o "lag" na aplicação, quando eu inicio o initTask da aplicação, isso é muito para a Main Thread?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque essa parte de código, assim como o erro.

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso!

Comment: pronto, editei e coloquei o que pediu em ordem de execução!

Comment: Você cria uma nova thread mas depois usa runOnUiThread.

Comment: Poderia me explicar melhor? esse é o erro? não entendo muito de thread ainda, comecei a trabalhar com android a 1 mes.

Comment: Todo o que está dentro de `runOnUiThread` corre na main thread, se esse processamento for demorado ele será a causa dessa informação. Isso não causa "erro", quanto muito é aberta uma caixa a informar que o app não responde.